# The remote TeamViewer is running an old version which is out of date

Tags: teamviewer

So the situation is as follows:
connect with portable TeamViewer 6 to a Quick Support Team Viewer remote partner.

Then this error occurs:
`The remote TeamViewer is running an old version which is out of date.`.
In fact the error occurs so quickly that it appears like it didn't attempt any remote communications at all.

Despite the error, the remote version is *not* out of date, as colleague can connect with exactly the same TeamViewer 6 version as me. What can it be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out to be the TV license. My colleague had a working license in his viewer while my teamviewer was in "free" mode.

So the error is misleading. It should have read "you are trying to connect with the wrong license mode" instead.

After keying in our license in the `teamviewer.ini` file it would connect just fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the "free" mode of Teamviewer for personal use and can't switch to a licensed version, **both** Teamviewer instances need to be version 14.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone reading this searching for an answer. If you both, you and your partner, use the very same version of the TeamViewer and you still encounter this problem then there's a possible solution.

One of you (the partner) has possibly an old version of TV **installed** on their machine, even though they run a new version (by invoking `TeamViewer_Setup.exe` from the shell).

Problem spotted a while ago, we both had the very latest version of TV but we still were unable to connect. Turned out my colleague had an old version installed. He uninstalled the old version, rerun the latest version from the command line and the connection succeeded.